# Can I alias an external table in redshift to remove the schema name?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We want to migrate tables to Spectrum, which requires defining an external schema

```
create external schema spectrum 
from data catalog 
database 'spectrumdb' 
iam_role 'my_iam_role'
create external database if not exists;
```

I created an external table in Redshift like this:

```
create external table spectrum.my_table(
 id bigint,
 accountId bigint,
 state varchar(65535),
 ) stored as parquet
 location 's3://some_bucket/my_table_files';
```

Is it possible to alias the table such that when querying it, I can call it `my_table_alias` instead of `spectrum.my_table`? Basically, we want to make the change to external tables opaque to clients of our Redshift instance (this means we can't change the table names). Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift does not have aliases, your best option is to create a view.

You need to use `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` option while creating the view since the view is on an external table.

If you like to not specify schema names or you have  a requirement like this create the view(s) in public schema or set the users default schema to the schema where the views are

`alter user .. set search_path to ..`

Additional benefits of using a view to access an external table are, you can

- rename columns to be more user friendly
- add or remove columns with view definition
- change data types and/or date/time formats
- you will have the ability to change name/structure of the external table without effecting user access

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: if I used a view, wouldn't that mean that every Spectrum query run on the view would run the view query? So I would lose the benefit of scanning fewer columns in Spectrum, because the whole table would be loaded into my Redshift cluster.

Comment: You could use partitioning and save your S3 files in parquet format. Check the following link for additional info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-performance.html

Comment: from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html "the query that defines the view is run every time the view is referenced in a query". Wouldn't this mean that the entire table would be loaded on every call to the view, even when using Parquet or partitioning?

Comment: I believe 'running query' and 'loading data' is two different things. In your first comment you have mentioned 'the whole table would be loaded into my Redshift cluster', I think this is not the case when you query an external table. Redshift Spectrum does not load data into Redshift cluster in order to return results, it only scans the data on S3 using 'Redshift Spectrum layer'

Comment: "Redshift Spectrum resides on dedicated Amazon Redshift servers that are independent of your cluster. Redshift Spectrum pushes many compute-intensive tasks, such as predicate filtering and aggregation, down to the Redshift Spectrum layer. Thus, Redshift Spectrum queries use much less of your cluster's processing capacity than other queries."   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html#c-spectrum-overview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If creating a view on an external table to rename it goes like this: `CREATE VIEW some_table AS SELECT * FROM spectrum.some_TABLE`, then we will be scanning all data in Parquet on every query to `some_table`, right?

Comment: Yes but do not forget to add `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` at the end of the view DDL. For scanning all data I think only columns specified in the `SELECT` should be looked at.